# Saving inkpresenter as png

Tags: silverlight, png, isolatedstorage

Is it possible to save an inkpresenter's content as a .png image?  If not is there an alternative to inkpresenter that can be drawn on, and saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to convert inkpresenter to png in two steps:

1. Render inkpresenter into WriteableBitmap (see [WriteableBitmap.Render Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.render%28VS.95%29.aspx))
2. Convert WriteableBitmap to png using [ImageTools](http://imagetools.codeplex.com/)